# Failed to print resource exception due to lack of space- SWI-prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a very simple base:

```
%rule base
parent(X, Y):- father(X, Y).
parent(X, Y):- mother(X, Y).
grandfather(X, Z):- father(X, Y), parent(Y, Z).
grandmother(X, Z):- mother(X, Y), parent(Y, Z).
ascendant(X, Y):- parent(X, Y).
ascendant(X, Z):- parent(X, Y), ascendant(Y, Z).
%fact
father(marcel, maurice).
father(maurice, juliette).
father(maurice, leon).

mother(henriette, maurice).
mother(cunegonde, leon).
```

if I test

```
father(marcel, maurice)
```

==> it returns true no prolem

But if I test for example:

```
father(X, maurice)
```

==>Failed to print resource exception due to lack of space
error(resource_error(stack),....

Anyone knows why does this happen? and how to solve this?

Im using Swi-prolog for window 10 64 bits and i have 44GB free on my local disk.

Im very new to code.

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong. This is not the program that fails with stack overflow:

```
?- father(marcel, maurice).
true.

?- father(X, maurice).
X = marcel.
```

Indeed, if you test

```
father(marcel, maurice).
```

the Prolog Processor will be able to to prove that this is the case: going from top to bottom through you program it will encounter `father(marcel, maurice).`, literally. Done.

If you ask for `X` for which `father(X, maurice)` is true, then the same thing happens, just with `X` set to `marcel`.

Please verify the program in your Prolog interpreter.